Firefox "lost" setting to always open new Tab from manually typed new URL address
Have recently setup a new Win10Pro laptop with latest Firefox x64.
On 4 other Win11Pro and Win10Pro laptops, whenever I type in manually a new address, FF automatically opens a new Tab on the extreme right side end with this new web page and PRESERVES all currently open Tabs.
This new laptop does not do that, it forces the page to load on the page I am currently working on.
I have to manually first open a new blank tab and then type in the new address.
Very annoying.
To illustrate steps on how this works correctly on my 4 "other" machines and what I have so far discovered.
Am using ebay just as an example "new address", this works correctly on 4 systems and does not work on the 1 new laptop.

There are a few tabs open(does not matter how many) and I can be reading or working on any of them
Type in manually in the address field ebay.com and press Enter, immediately a new tab opens to the right and switches focus to this new Tab with the loaded page showing.

On the new system, the ebay.com opens on the tab I am currently working, thus "destroying" the data I want to keep open in that currently focused tab.
In about config with the parameter search neww
These are the values shown on all 5 machines, identically set on all
   browser.link.open_newwindow  3   
   browser.link.open_newwindow.disabled_in_fullscreen   false   
   browser.link.open_newwindow.override.external    -1  
   browser.link.open_newwindow.restriction  0   
   security.xfocsp.hideOpenInNewWindow  true    
   services.sync.prefs.sync.browser.link.open_newwindow true`

for about preferences#searchResults with the parameter tab,
all settings are checked identically

Solved
browser.search.openintab    true
browser.urlbar.openintab    true

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
